# PostgreSQL поиск по части строки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как для уже заданного слова это я знаю:

```
where name like ‘%abc%’
```

Но как сделать, чтобы я это слово вводил сам?
То есть вот я создаю функцию:

```
Create or replace function choose_actors2(char)
```

Ввожу этот чар, но а как дальше понять не могу.

Функция:

```
Create or replace function choose_actors2(integer, char) returns table (actor char(20), oldfilm char(20), god integer) as $$
begin
    return query select
      actor.name,
      oldfilm.name,
      oldfilm.year
    from actor
    inner join oldfilm
      on actor.id_oldfilm = oldfilm.id
    where (oldfilm.year=$1 or oldfilm.name like ‘%$2%’);
    return;
end $$ language ‘plpgsql’;
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста куда Вы вводите слово и саму функцию неплохо было бы увидеть

Comment: Добавил функцию.

Comment: Ввожу слово при вызове этой функции через select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользоваться [конкатенацией строк](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)?

```
oldfilm.name like '%' || $2 || '%'
```